# Date axis as Value axis with OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart in Excel where the value axis has dates. I need the distance between ticks to be 1 month (not 30 days, not 31 days: 1 month). I find that, while I can use the format unit option and date cells to show month and year in the value axis, the distance between ticks isn't 1 month and so the bars don't have the length they should, and I can't change that. The best I can do is setting the major and minor units to 30, so they get a distance of 30 days, but as I said, that screws up with the chart visualization.

Is there any way to create a Date axis as a Value axis?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 1` is for your *1* part of the axis, and `.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnitScale = xlMonths` for *Months*

If you don't have the constants in open xml, then **xlCategory = 1**, and **xlMonths = 1**

Comment: This is the thing: the months aren't in the category axis, they are in the value axis (it's a Gantt chart using stacked bars)